# "No release file" errors when trying to upgrade from version 17.10 to 18.04

Tags: updates, update-manager, repository

While upgrading from ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 it is showing an error regarding zesty-update release and zesty-security release.

```
E:The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release'
  does not have a Release file.
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely,
  and is therefore disabled by default.
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E:The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release'
  does not have a Release file.`
```

The above error is showing and I am also unable to update also for the same reason.

What should I do now to overcome this problem?

Comment: **Zesty** *was* Ubuntu 17.04 (2017 April release,  EOL 13-Jan-2018), **Artful** *is* 17.10 (2017 October release). Your errors as posted imply you are running 17.04 which is **EOL**, and post-EOL the repositories are moved from `archive.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` causing the errors you've listed (until you modify your system accordingly), and @AmanMittal's question.  If you're trying to upgrade 17.04 to 18.04 there is an additional step needed; so please confirm your version.

Comment: Thanks @AmanMittal - i've 'improved' my text (*i hope*)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like what happened to me after an interupted do-release-upgrade. Try the following:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

If this works, try doing your release upgrade again.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```